# wow.js and animate.css don't work anymore

Tags: html, css, scroll, animate.css, wow.js

I have a website with wow.js and animate.css effects. everything work fine here: http://doggystyle.businesscatalyst.com/

Then I made some changes and uploaded to another testing url, so the animation effects don't work now. check here: http://doggy-test.businesscatalyst.com/

Can you help me to find out a problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I searched your code and I believe you need to delete this line of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/floatjs.js"></script>
```

If you need that code really bad you need to debug line 20, it looks live a value is messed up due to your other javascript.

Answer (score 0):

WOW().init was called before wow.js.

now WOW().init is calling at the end and webpage works fine.